# Mesh Control Problem

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh

I am having trouble combining two graphical objects. The problem has to do with controlling mesh lines. The simplest failing example is combining a circle graphics primitive with a RegionPlot. Either works separately, but when combined I get undesirable side effects.

Here is the circle. Note that its circumference is opaque black.

```
 gr1 = Graphics[
   Circle[{0, 0}, 5],
   ImageSize -> 200,
   Axes -> False,
   Ticks -> False
 ]
```

[image: Graphics Circle]

Here is the RegionPlot. Note that no mesh lines appear.

```
Parametric2CartesianCenter[a_, b_, \[Theta]_] := 
  {a * Cos[\[Theta]], b * Sin[\[Theta]]};
point1 = Parametric2CartesianCenter[5, 3, 2 \[Pi]/3];
point2 = Parametric2CartesianCenter[5, 3, 7 \[Pi]/16];
constraintLeft = x >= point1[[1]];
constraintRight = x <= point2[[1]];
constraintCircle = x^2 + y^2 <= 5^2;
rp1 = RegionPlot[
  constraintLeft && constraintRight && constraintCircle, {x, -5, 
  5}, {y, 5, -5},
  ImageSize -> 200,
  Axes -> False,
  Ticks -> False,
  Frame -> None
]
```

[image: Default RegionPlot]

Here is what happens if I try to combine them using Show in either order. Note that if the circle appears first, mesh lines are displayed, but when the order is swapped, the circle is no longer black. My goal is to have no mesh lines and a black circle.

```
s1ab = Row[{Show[gr1, rp1], Show[rp1, gr1]}]
```

[image: Using Show in both orders]

I am aware of the TransparentPolygonMesh option. It works as expected when set on the uncombined constructs.

```
rp2 = RegionPlot[
  constraintLeft && constraintRight && constraintCircle, {x, -5, 
  5}, {y, 5, -5},
  ImageSize -> 200,
  Axes -> False,
  Ticks -> False,
  Frame -> None,
  Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}
];
gr2 = Graphics[
  Circle[{0, 0}, 5],
  ImageSize -> 200,
  Axes -> False,
  Ticks -> False,
  Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> False}
];
```

[image]

However, when combining the constructs, in either order, I still see the anomalous behavior:

```
sb2 = Row[{Show[rp2, gr2], Show[gr2, rp2]}]
```

[image: Anomaly]

Here are some of the other workarounds I have tried:

- In addition to Show, I have tried combining the two constructs using Overlay, Prolog, and Epilog. I have also tried placing First@RegionPlot into the the same Graphics call as the call to Circle.
- I have tried placing the TransparentPolygonMesh option independently into the calls to Graphics and RegionPlot. I have also tried setting the option in the call to Show.
- I have tried MeshFunction->{}. I have tried Mesh->None. I have tried MeshStyle->{}. I have MeshShading->{}. I have tried BoundaryStyle->None.

None of these approaches solve the problem.

I realize I could likely work around the problem either by representing the circle as a region and doing a RegionUnion or by devising a texture. However, my real problem involves an extensive series of such combinations using an existing collection of Graphics and RegionPlots that I wish to combine in various ways. It seems that there should be a way to control this behavior.

**Question:** How can I control the behavior of mesh lines without effecting the presentation of other graphics constructs with which it is combined?

I am using Mathematica 12.1.0.0 on a MacBook Pro, running OSX 10.13.4.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on `12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)`. `Row[{Show[gr1, rp1], Show[rp1, gr1]}]` (either order) does not show a mesh and the circle is black.

Comment: `s1ab` does not display a mesh. Neither does `sb2`. I am using 12.2 on Win7. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXtmi.png

Comment: Seems to be a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: Indeed, the problem has been fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a use case for this other than display? It would be nice to see how these two forms can be combined & result in an anisotropic mesh, while also enabling a display of the major mesh vertices using vector graphics to provide you with a high quality display. Or something similar...

Comment: My use case is strictly the display of geometric diagrams.